# Is there a way to review a Rmarkdown document in a collaborative way?

Tags: r-markdown

I am working remotely with some colleagues on a Rmarkdown document, and I would like to make a simple review of the file (especially the comment part and not the code), and then send it back to others with my reviews embeded in the document, like a word document review or a kind of Overleaf review. I have made some research on the topic, but I didn't find something that feet my needs as explained. Please, Is there a way to add some review in a Rmakdown document and sent it back (either online or not)?

Comment: are you using `git`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/)

> Etherpad is a highly customizable Open Source online editor providing collaborative editing in really real-time.

Or, better: [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)

> With StackEdit, you can share collaborative workspaces, thanks to the Google Drive synchronization mechanism. If two collaborators are working on the same file at the same time, StackEdit takes care of merging the changes.

Or, even better: [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/)

> HackMD is a realtime, multiplatform collaborative markdown note editor.
>   This means that you can write notes with other people on your desktop, tablet or even on the phone.

Comment: Thanks very much @Rushikumar for your response. I will just keep the markdown file (or even compile to markdown), upload it online and share.

Comment: HackMD doesn't seem to like .Rmd files. Any suggestions for collaborative work with Rmd? Would be a bit awkward to convert back and fourth with pandoc but possible I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you considering trackdown https://claudiozandonella.github.io/trackdown/

trackdown is an R package that offers a simple answer to collaborative writing and editing of R Markdown (or Sweave) documents. With trackdown, the local .Rmd (or .Rnw) file is uploaded as plain-text in Google Drive where, thanks to the easily readable Markdown (or LaTeX) syntax and the well-known online interface offered by Google Docs, collaborators can easily contribute to the writing and editing of the narrative part of the document. After integrating all authors’ contributions, the final document can be downloaded and rendered locally.

You can find more details at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68014082/12481476 or in the package documentation https://claudiozandonella.github.io/trackdown/