# rmarkdown collaboration without google drive

Tags: r, git, r-markdown, redoc

I am spinning up a project with 4-5 collaborators at all levels of R / markdown / git proficiency. Looking for a solution that allows editors of text/prose to stay in a word processing ecosystem to the extent practicable.

Saw this solution using `trackdown` ; unfortunately our infosec folks prohibit Google Drive.
https://community.rstudio.com/t/collaborating-on-r-markdown-documents/107771

Saw this SO using `redoc` but the gitlab documentation & issue list make it seem as though its not very stable.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61215217/9806500

Is there a similar solution with sharepoint/teams, OR a solution that allows for offline reconciliation of prose with the main rmd?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're looking for Markdown or another lightweight text markup language, then you definitely _don't_ want word processing tools, since those will overwhelmingly not produce nice text markup.

Comment: @bk2204 I need a mechanism for non-git and non-rmarkdown people to branch, edit, and commit changes to prose. Rmarkdown is being used for its ability to support inline code, rather than its lightweight design. Have any suggestions which address constraints cited above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something very much like the requested functionality is on the development roadmap for rmarkdown / quatro, but is not currently available. Special thanks to `@Jannik` on the R4DS Slack for bringing this to my attention.

https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/405